# Review breaks when post becomes unavailable for review

Tags: bug, review-queues, low-quality-posts

Sometimes, a post becomes "unavailable for review", an euphemism for "deleted", while it is being reviewed.

For some reason, finishing the review then causes the UI to break with a JavaScript error.

As a workaround, just re-loading the page works, which then shows the same post with its updated status.

Can we please not have a hysteric breakdown when the post is deleted out from under us?

PS: I'm only sure it happens in the LQRQ.